# Drupal Views - Hide a Field if annother Field is not empty? / Show a Field unless its empty, then show a differnt Field?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

With Drupal Views, how can I hide a Field if another Field is not empty? In other words, how can I show a Field unless its empty, then show a different Field?

I have the following;

Node1
fieldA - text for field A in Node 1
fieldB - text for field B in Node 1

Node2
fieldA - (empty)
fieldB - text for field B in Node 2

I want to show fieldA, unless it's empty in which case i wanted to show fieldB. So my View would show;

'text for field A in Node 1'
'text for field B in Node 2'

How can I do this? I can hide a filed if its empty, but how can I hide a field if another field is not being hidden?

In case it matters, the reason im doing this is im using image cache to generate thumbnails for a gallery. However for some thumbnails I want to be able to upload a different image to be used as a thumbnail.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe you'd like to accept the below the answer by clicking on the tick to its left? It would be good to do this for some of your other questions too, even the ones you answered yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://drupal.org/node/941908 . Anyway, there is no easy solution.

Comment: Thanks, I guess a little php is needed now and again.

Answer (score 2):

It would appear this can now be achieved using the 'rewrite if empty' behavior, which allows replacement tokens from the view - the trick is that you need to put 'field b' first in the order of the view fields, and hide it from displaying.  Then in the 'field a' settings, set the no results behavior to the token for 'field b'  (usually something like [field_b]) ...logically this means if field A has a value it will be displayed, but if not (no results) field b will be displayed instead.

Comment: Hi @ryantdecker would the Rewrite if Empty behaviours allow me to achieve this:
If Field C (Finish Date) is Empty, then Hide Field B (breaker line)?

Comment: @AuxiliaryJoel - I think you're on the right track, but the logic would be a little different: make field b hidden, customize the output from field c to include field b & c, then hide C (which includes b) if it's empty.

Comment: ah I see. So Field C would have the short code for field B+C in it's Rewrite setting, and if it's empty - hide the Rewrite?

Comment: Thanks for your help here. It helped me achieve exactly what I wanted in quite a simple way that I otherwise would have dreaded providing preprocess coding for but now instead I can easily handle it directly within the View.

Comment: Always nice when you answer a 5 year old question and someone finds it useful.  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

http://drupal.org/sandbox/benclark/1213836

A new sandbox module is available that provides this functionality.